# Paypal confirmation when the transaction has been successfully done

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal

I have redirected my website to Paypal on `Buy Now` button, but where should i place my code when the transaction has been successfully done.
Can someone help please? I need to change my status in my biding to paid.

```
 Dim temp As String = Request.QueryString("user").ToString
    Dim temp1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(temp)
    Dim LastName As String
    Dim WinningPrice As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim country As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim FirstName As String
    Using con1 As New SqlConnection(_start)
        'Build your SQL String'
        Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT Item.Name, BID.WinningPrice, Member.LastName, Member.FirstName,Member.Email, Member.Country FROM  Item INNER JOIN Seller ON Item.SellerID = Seller.SellerID INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID INNER JOIN BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID INNER JOIN Member ON Seller.MemberID = Member.MemberID WHERE (Member.Status = 'Available') AND (Seller.SellerStatus = 'Available') AND (BID.Status = 'Won') AND (Auction.Status = 'Expired') and BID.BidID=@bidid"
        'Open your connection'
        con1.Open()

        'Build your Command to execute'
        Dim myCommand1 As New SqlCommand(sql1, con1)

        'Grab your parameter'

        'Add your parameter'
        myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@bidid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = temp1
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = myCommand1.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            If reader.Read() Then
                ' etc
                Name = reader.GetString(0)
                WinningPrice = Convert.ToString(reader.GetDouble(1))
                LastName = reader.GetString(2)
                FirstName = reader.GetString(3)
                email = reader.GetString(4)
                country = reader.GetString(5)

                Dim price As Object
                'Converting String Money Value Into Decimal
                price = Convert.ToDouble(WinningPrice)
                'declaring empty String
                Dim returnURL As String = ""
                returnURL += "https://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=" + email
                'Passing Item Name as dynamic
                returnURL += Convert.ToString("&item_name=") & Name
                'Assigning Name as Statically to Parameter

                returnURL += Convert.ToString("&first_name") & FirstName

                'Assigning Name as Statically to Parameter

                returnURL += Convert.ToString("&last_name") & LastName
                'Assigning City as Statically to Parameter



                returnURL += Convert.ToString("&country") & country
                'Passing Amount as Dynamic
                returnURL += "&amount=" + price.ToString
                'Passing Currency as your 
                returnURL += "&currency=USD"
                'If transactioin has been successfully performed, redirect SuccessURL page- this page will be designed by developer
                returnURL += "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL").ToString()
                'retturn Url if Customer Wants To Cancel the Transaction

                'If transactioin has been failed, redirect FailedURL page- this page will be designed by developer
                returnURL += "&cancel_return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FailedURL").ToString()



                Response.Redirect(returnURL)

            End If
        End If
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a SuccessUrl parameter; when paypal completes it is going to send a notification to that page - so you should put code in the Page_Load event of your SuccessUrl to parse the query parms returned, and do whatever local processing you need to do there.

Comment: but will the successURl passs the bidid that he has trigged so that i can set the bid to paid?

Comment: but will the successURl passs the bidid that he has trigged so that i can set the bid to paid? really my question is how to pass the id of bid that has been sucessfull to the SucessUrl so i can get the id of the bid and change his status to paid

Comment: You should be able to add the bidid as a parameter on the sucessurl, so that if you pass in mysuccesspage.aspx?bidid=12345, it should call you back with that custom parameter attached.

Comment: but the url is in the webconfig, will i need to remove it from the web config?

Comment: No, you can keep the 'base' url in the web.config, just append your custom data to it before submitting it to paypal.

Comment: can you give an example please really lost here

Comment: bear in my that the bidid will change for each product, for each sale

Comment: Please can you give an example please